# javaScript Animating Images onmouseover/onmouseout

Tags: javascript, animation, settimeout, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have an animation (41 frames) of a door opening, I want to use javaScript to make it open onmouseover, and I want it to go back to frame 1 onmouseout. I don't think I'm doing it quite right for the onmouseout part. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
HTML:
    <div onmouseover="startAnimation()" onmouseout="stopAnimation()" id="door2"></div>
    <div id="door">
    <img src="images/Animation_Door/0001.png">
    <img src="images/Animation_Door/0002.png">
    <img src="images/Animation_Door/0003.png">
    ...etc...(41 frames)

css:
    #door img{
    display: none;
    }

    #door img:first-child {
    display: block;
    }

javaScript:
    function startAnimation() { 
    var frames = document.getElementById("door").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;

    for (i=0; i<41; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
    }, 50*i);
    }
    }

    function stopAnimation() {
    var frames = document.getElementById("door").children;
    var frameCount = frames.length;

    for (i=0; i<1; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
    frames[++i % frameCount].style.display = "none";
    frames[i % frameCount].style.display = "block";
    }, 50*i);
    }
    }
```

here's a link to it:
http://www.reveriesrefined.com/test

Comment: link is returning a 403 forbidden state

Comment: Shouldn't the for loop in stopAnimation have "i<41" instead of "i<1"?

Comment: I can't seem to fix the link, but if you just paste it into your browser it should work.

Comment: When the for loop in stopAnimation has i<41 it animates the door shut, I just want it to go straight to the first frame without any animation.

Comment: It is going straight to the first frame with no animation for me. What are you trying to change?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is probably more like what you want:

```
var ti, frame = 0,
frames = document.getElementById('door').children;

function resetAnimation() {
    frame = 0;
    frames[0].style.display = 'block';
    for (var i = 1; i < frames.length; i++) {
        frames[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function startAnimation() {
    console.log('start animation');
    resetAnimation();
    ti = setInterval(function() {
        frames[frame].style.display = 'none';
        frame ++;
        if (frame >= frames.length) frame = 0;
        frames[frame].style.display = 'block';
    }, 50);
}
function stopAnimation() {
    if (ti) {
        clearInterval(ti);
        ti = undefined;
    }
    resetAnimation();
}​
```

Note that it's usually more appropriate to use setInterval than setTimeout when you want a continuous animation. A global variable stores which frame we are currently viewing. resetAnimation sets the frame to zero and sets the display accordingly. startAnimation sets an interval timer that hides the old frame, increases the frame by one, and shows the new frame, every 50ms. Stop animation simply clears the interval timer and resets the animation.

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working. It wont even start the animation. I've tried onmouseover="startAnimation()" onmouseout="stopAnimation()" and I've also tried onClick, but it doesn't start the animation. Any idea why? I'm trying a bunch of things but can't seem to get the animation to work with your code.

Comment: Works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vHbn5/3/). In your original code the event handlers are on an empty div (id="door2") so you may not even be able to see the div that you need to put the mouse over?